# How to use mongoose-to-swagger

Tags: rest, mongoose, swagger, swagger-ui-express

I'm trying to create a REST-API just from my Mongoose Model.
After trying out multiple libraries I don't understand if this is possible, because I was only able to output the Swagger Schema using mongoose-to-swagger which looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'Time',
  required: [ 'startingTime' ],
  properties: {
    project: { type: 'string', required: false },
    description: { type: 'string', required: false },
    startingTime: { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' },
    endingTime: { type: 'string', required: false, format: 'date-time' },
    _id: { type: 'string' }
  }
}
```

But when creating a SwaggerSpec using swagger-jsdoc it looks like the following and works. But that way I still need to annotate the Model...

```
{
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  info: {
    title: 'Your API Documentation',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description: 'API documentation generated with Swagger'
  },
  paths: {
    '/api/v1/Time': { get: [Object], post: [Object] },
    '/api/v1/Time/{id}': { get: [Object], put: [Object], patch: [Object], delete: [Object] }
  },
  components: { schemas: { Time: [Object] } },
  tags: []
}
```

Mongoose Model / Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    project: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minLength: 1,
        maxLength: 50,
        trim: false,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        maxLength: 100,
        trim: false,
    },
    startingTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    },
    endingTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: false,
        validate: {
            validator: function (value) {
                return this.startingTime <= value;
            },
            message: 'Ending time must be after the starting time',
        },
    },
});

const Time = mongoose.model('Time', TimeSchema);
module.exports = Time;
```

Tried to dynamically create a Swagger documentation using swagger-jsdoc which works but only with annotations.

When using mongoose-to-swagger it does not work because it looks like the output is not the array that swagger-ui-express expects.